# Parse nested XML file and get the value of previous tag in python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a huge nested .xml file with a lots of entries. What I need is to find a previous value if I know the child ID.

Extraction of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nodes>
    <node>
        <node_id>0x2D</node_id>
        <num_1>11</num_1>
        <num_2>905.908</num_2>
        <signs>
            <sign>
                <sign_id>30</sign_id>
                <name>INDEX_0</name>
                <size_b>842069</size_b>
                <content>
                    <models>
                        <model>1_x</model>
                        <model>2_x</model>
                        <model>3_x</model>
                        <model>4_x</model>
                    </models>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <value>VALUE1</value>
                            <folder_ids>
                                <folder_id>012345678</folder_id>
                            </folder_ids>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <value>VALUE2</value>
                            <folder_ids>
                                <folder_id>1235365454</folder_id>
                            </folder_ids>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <value>VALUE3</value>
                            <folder_ids>
                                <folder_id>3562377456</folder_id>
                                <folder_id>3566743626</folder_id>
                                <folder_id>012345678</folder_id>
                            </folder_ids>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <value>VALUE4</value>
                            <folder_ids>
                                <folder_id>34627876</folder_id>
                            </folder_ids>
                        </image>
                        <image>
.
.
.
```

So for example if I need to find all values that contain 012345678 folder_id.
I tried to use lxml library.
Simple code:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('D:\\test_nested_xml.xml')
#root = etree.Element("root")
for element in tree.iter(tag="folder_id"):
    if element.text == '012345678':
        print("%s - %s" % (element.text, element.getparent))
```

But in output I get following entries:

```
012345678 - <bound method _Element.getparent of <Element folder_id at 0x2cf2648>>
012345678 - <bound method _Element.getparent of <Element folder_id at 0x2cf2620>>
```

And it is not what I need.

Expected result for me is something like:

```
012345678 - VALUE1
012345678 - VALUE3
```

Could someone help me how to correctly parse xml file and get what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently printing the method itself.

```
print("%s - %s" % (element.text, element.getparent))
```

If you want to see what the method *returns*, you need to call it.

```
print("%s - %s" % (element.text, element.getparent()))
```

---

You can also use XPath to select the desired values in one step:

```
search_id = '012345678'

for value in tree.xpath(f"//image[folder_ids/folder_id='{search_id}']/value"):
    print(value.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, Tomalak. Forgot to mention that I tried to use: print("%s - %s" % (element.text, element.getparent()))

But I get:

012345678 - <Element folder_ids at 0x3b82120>
012345678 - <Element folder_ids at 0x3b82120> 

The second way you advised is not working. I'm getting:
```
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Comment: @hothead You're printing the element. If you want to print the element text, you need to print the element `.text`. I thought you would make that connection yourself.

Comment: About the "invalid predicate" error - I've used the wrong method (`tree.iterfind()` instead of `tree.xpath()`). That's corrected now.